# lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c

I get the following error: *lvalue required as left operand of assignment*
for this function code:

```
typedef struct {
  int nbIndividus;
  int nbVariables;
  distance_t *distancesReference;
  double **target;
  double *E;
  double *lag;
} functionData_t;

    double myfunc (unsigned n,const double *x, double *grad, void *my_func_data)
{
   int i,j,k,t,ind1,ind2,a,test_nb;
   double temp,sigma,eta,distanceCarre,sommeObj,distance,compteurDistance,somme,objectifFunction,Somme,*Array_val_E;
   int nbIndividus,nbVariables,NbDisplacement,nb_val_E;
   double **target;
   double *E;
   double *lag ;

   distance_t *distancesReference;
   functionData_t *functionData=(functionData_t *)my_func_data;


   nbIndividus=functionData->nbIndividus;
   nbVariables=functionData->nbVariables; 
   target= functionData->target;
   E= functionData->E;
   lag=functionData->lag;
   distancesReference=functionData->distancesReference; 
   sommeObj=0;
   somme=0;
   sigma=0.13;
   eta=0.5;
   nb_val_E=114814;
   compteurDistance=0;
   NbDisplacement=0;
  for(k=1;k<nbIndividus;k++){
   compteurDistance=compteurDistance+(nbIndividus-k);
  }


  for(i=0;i<compteurDistance;i++){
        ind1=distancesReference[i].i;
        ind2=distancesReference[i].j;
        distance=distancesReference[i].distance;
        Somme=0;
        for(k=0;k<nbVariables;k++) {
         temp=target[ind1][k]-target[ind2][k]+x[ind1*nbVariables+k]-x[ind2*nbVariables+k];
     Somme+=temp*temp;
        }
        distanceCarre=Somme;
        for(t=0;t<=nb_val_E;t++){
           Array_val_E[t]=fabs(E[t]-(distanceCarre/(4*sigma*sigma)));
        }
        index=min_array(Array_val_E,nb_val_E);
        sommeObj+=(distancesReference[i].distance)*(distancesReference[i].distance)+distanceCarre+2*sigma*sigma*nbVariables-2*sqrt(3.14)*(distancesReference[i].distance)*sigma*val_lag(index);
     }

    objectifFunction=sommeObj;

    return objectifFunction;

}
```

I think that the problem is in the vector E, but i cannot find the origin of this error. Can someone help me please to fix it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which line the error is in?

Comment: In this line:  index=min_array(Array_val_E,nb_val_E);

Comment: where did you define `index`?

Comment: I don't see any declaration of `index`.

Comment: Oups I forgot to define `index` :/

Comment: @Heva When you see an error, how do you approach it except of asking on SO? You see an error about an lvalue of an expression. Shouldn't you check what this lvalue is as the very first thing?

Comment: Note that you're going to have a runtime error on the line `Array_val_E[t]=fabs(E[t]-(distanceCarre/(4*sigma*sigma)));` - you've declared `Array_val_E` as a pointer, but you never set it to point to anything.  You're indexing into an indeterminate memory location.  And what do you have against whitespace?

Comment: For an undeclared variable gcc gives me: `error: ‘index’ undeclared (first use in this function)` - which is much better than `lvalue required as left operand of assignment` If I do `5 = 8;`gcc gives: `error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment` - is the missing index declaration really the cause?

Comment: @4386427 It seems that we are not given the full picture here..

Comment: @Heva - you should add declaration of `index` and let us know if that solves the problem. I doubt it will.

Comment: yes, the declaration of `index` solves the problem. But now i have an error of segmentation.  Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to declare `index`.

The reason for the apparently strange error message - "lvalue required..." as opposed to something like "'index' undeclared..." - is that there is a library function called "index" which you've happened to include a declaration of (most likely [this one](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man3/index.3.html)).

When you're not hiding that function with a variable declaration, you're attempting to assign to a function (which you can't, for obvious reasons).